# Should I encrypt my dropbox app key/secret?

Tags: ios, dropbox

We're adding Dropbox support to our app, and we now have an "app key" and "app secret" for it. I could just keep those as plain text in the code, as listed in the sync API tutorial:

```
   DBAccountManager* accountMgr =
    [[DBAccountManager alloc] initWithAppKey:@"hf2hf892hf9y29h" secret:@"n29fh82h4f"];
```

(Note: that is a made up key and secret, not our real one.)

But then it'd be super easy for someone to extract them from the app if they wanted to. To prevent that, we could add some sort of basic encryption to make the keys harder to find, but obviously the keys are still going to be used in a call to the DropBox account manager at some point, so there's no way to keep them perfectly secure.

Is this something anybody worries about, or is it just a fact of life that someone who really wants to can go in and find out the keys?

Answer (score 2):

> Is this something anybody worries about

Any sane developer worries about it. Do use some form of encryption.

Hint: my attitude - when I download an app from the AppStore which requires some form of login to [insert arbitrary webservice here], I usually decrypt the binary and run `otool` or at least `strings` on it. If it has plaintext passwords/OAuth keys/SSL keypairs etc. in it, I usually trash it immediately.

> is it just a fact of life that someone who really wants to can go in and find out the keys?

Practically, [yes, even the keychain isn't secure ;-)](http://github.com/ptoomey3/Keychain-Dumper). This is, however, **not an excuse** for not trying to do your best if the subject is the security of your data and/or that of your users.

Comment: It seems like you're talking about the app storing a username and password, which isn't how the dropbox integration works - the app itself has a "key" and "secret" which are totally decoupled from user credentials. Am I misreading your answer? The dropbox API handles user credentials for you, so the app author never even sees the username / password for the user.

Comment: @Colen I am afraid you are. I've worked with the Dropbox SDK myself. As you state, you need an app ID and a secret key in order Dropbox to authorize your application. If you hard-code these in the app, a simple `strings` will reveal them in plaintext. This means that one can trivially issue an identity theft attack, disguising his malicious application as yours, hence exposing the security of your users to the attacker.

Comment: But the user would still have to log in to Dropbox through the malicious application, right? So it'd have to go: 1) Somehow download malicious application (hard by itself on iOS); 2) User actively logs in to dropbox via malicious application; 3) Attacker can steal files. If the user is going to log into dropbox anyway, the attacker could just provide a fake "dropbox login" screen and steal *all* the user's files that way.

Comment: @Colen of course, there are so many ways to steal data. But: #1 - of course it's "hard", but haven't you seen fake apps almost perfectly copying the GUI of another one? #2 - he now does, since he didn't notice the difference; #3 - and he can now steal files.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your concern is valid. You should put it in the keychain.

However, nothing is perfectly secure, not even the keychain, as [Carbonic Acid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonic_acid) said already. Sometimes one makes the mistake of focusing on one security threat and disregarding another, larger problem. It's a lot like optimization, (except it's harder to profile security than performance).

You don't need to make your secrets impossible to steal, just more expensive to steal than to acquire elsewhere. And Dropbox API keys aren't exactly hens' teeth.

Comment: Isn't that just going to move the target? Sure, I could put the key / secret in the keychain somewhere, but then all someone has to do is find the place where I put them in the keychain and extract them from there.

Comment: Kind of, but in theory it's harder to pull stuff out of the keychain than the app.

Answer (score 0):

A more up-to-date answer in case someone else stumbles upon this question.

Dropbox API OAuth 2.0 now features PKCE which does *not* require client secret to generate access token. They have even specifically outlined this use case in [their oauth guide](https://developers.dropbox.com/oauth-guide):

| if your app is | it should |
| --- | --- |
| A client-side Desktop app or mobile app that requires background access | Use the OAuth code flow with PKCE, with refresh tokens. |

If you will look at the [/oauth2/token](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#oauth2-token) API doc example, you will see that PKCE method does *not* use client secret.

This additional guide - [PKCE: What and Why?](https://dropbox.tech/developers/pkce--what-and-why-) - provides some basic info for implementing it.

Edit:

When PKCE is not appropriate?

<s>In case of Dropbox implementation, PKCE is *not* appropriate when you need to access Dropbox API in the background i.e. without user's interaction. This is due to the fact that, `oauth/token` does *not* grant you a refresh token. (Refresh token is used to generate a new access token *without* user interaction)</s>

To get a refresh token while using PKCE, you need to supply `token_access_type=offline` to `oauth2/authorize` (similar to their code flow). At this point, I don't know *why* their guide recommends code flow with refresh tokens if PKCE can achieve the same *without* storing or using client secret.